# I have updated my files on github now how to update the files on my website?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have updated my files on GitHub now how to update the files on my website? I have two branches linked to it one, is master branch other one is gh_pages.

[image: Stuck at this]

Comment: You should have given much more details about what you are trying to do. It seems you are trying to publish your web site to github pages. Then you should search for github pages deployment git commands.

Comment: i am just trying to update my website i have updated the files and made the changes in git but i dont know how to update them on my web my web is still using the old code

Answer (score 0):

1. Working with two different branch; one for repository other one for
   github pages

   If you have two different branch one for development and one for    deployment than you should do as I said in the comment section: When    you working with github pages you should deploy your changes through    git commands. Github pages does not automatically refresh itself    according to your repository. You should create your build file by    running `npm run build` then should run deploy command through    `gh-pages -d build`.

   To do that of course you should have gh-pages installed already through npm.

   And of course if you want to make auto deployment whenever you commit changes to your master branch than you want a CI/CD pipeline such as jenkins, travis, circleci etc.
2. Working with same branch both for repository and github-pages

   If you have the same branch for your github-pages site than it should automatically update itself already. Make sure you have the same branch for your repo and web site settings.

Comment: The issue was resolved i was doing a small mistake thanks for your precious time